# HTTPS Urls When SSL Terminated At Load Balancer

Tags: asp.net-core, https

I need my ASP.NET Core application to return `https` urls when I return a `CreatedAtActionResult` or get the current request url using `UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(Request)` from my API controller.  I do not want to have my service handle https traffic, so using https redirection is undesirable.  Ideally, any process that generates a url / uri should be able to override the schema to `https://`.

**Background**

I have a service running in Docker on AWS Fargate that is behind a load balancer that is terminating SSL traffic and forwarding requests as HTTP to my Asp.Net Core API.  That API has actions that return a `CreatedAtActionResult` that forms the url provided in the `Location` header response.  Unfortunately those urls are `http://` and not `https://` because my service doesn't know it should return `https://`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by writing a custom middleware that uses a configuration value to identify what environment I am running in, and selectively changing the incoming request.  Hope that this helps the next person that encounters this problem!

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // Rewrite the inbound Request when running remotely (where this key isn't set)
    if (Configuration["RunningEnvironment"] == null)
    {
        context.Request.IsHttps = true;
        context.Request.Scheme = "https";
    }

    await next.Invoke();
});
```

Comment: This put me on the right track, and it made me wonder if there was existing middleware. Turns out there, is, out of the box. 
ForwardedHeadersMiddleware. And there is the ForwardedHeadersExtension, which allows you to add `app.UseForwardedHeaders( options )`. Then, if the load balancer sets a header, like `X-Forwarded-Proto`, these headers are used to configure the context like you do, but based on those header values.